# Understanding how the total # of comparisons is derived for the worst case in the "Brute-Force String Matching" algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, strings, matching

The Total number of comparisons for the worst case in the "Brute-Force String Matching" algorithm is: `(n-m+1)` where `n = lenght of string` and where `m = length of pattern`, that all makes sense to me except I want to be SURE my understanding of the `+1` is correct. Let me set up an example first:

`n = "four"`

`m = "it"`

So we check,

[image]

My understanding is, there is a `+1` in the equation so that when we reach `r` in `four` we do not check it because `it` would spill over out of the length of the string, even if it were correct. So the `+1` stops it from being checked. Is this the correct thinkign for why the `+1` is in `(n-m+1)`?

Comment: Check your reasoning with "four" "its".

Comment: @greybeard Sorry for the late response! My reasoning does work with `four` and `its`, perfect! Thank you for giving a goal to complete to check my reasoning, extremely helpful.